# How to change label names in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, charts

How to access and change the label named "level_1" on the top right corner? 
   I posted a question earlier and I found a solution using this code to display my chart:

```
df = df.groupby(['Time']).apply(lambda x: x['Type'].value_counts())
df = df.reset_index().pivot('Time','level_1','Type')
```

This fixed my dataframes. When I `print(df.columns)` I get this:

```
Index(['buy', 'sell'], dtype='object', name='level_1')
```

So why does level_1 appear here? I've never hardcoded that name and I'm asking what it stands for. When I try to change 'level_1' variable on the code above, it gives me errors.

https://prnt.sc/rxumax

Comment: The question is not about matplotlib but pandas. Tag removed